# How to paginate card-block 4 in a row 12 on a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I have cards that can be filtered by title and I want to create 4 cards per row (which I have done) and 3 rows per page.

When you search the cards have to be responsive and fill the preceding slot.

For example when I search "card four" because there is only one title with that name you will see it in the position of the initial position of "card one".

I have many cards I want to display but want to do it across multiple pages will keeping this same search functionality.

I tried using a table (without cards) which can be done successfully. I can't find documentation about having card-block display across multiple rows and paginate. Here's the codepen: https://codepen.io/dnorton94/pen/NWKGagz

```
<!-- search bar -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 mb-3">
      <input type="text" id="myFilter" class="form-control" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search by MBTI personality type..">
    </div>
  </div>
<!-- results -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" id="myItems">
    <!-- card one -->
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-block">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/500x200" alt="Card image cap">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card one</h5>
            <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- card two -->
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-block">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/500x200" alt="Card image cap">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card two</h5>
            <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- card three -->
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-block">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/500x200" alt="Card image cap">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card three</h5>
            <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- card four -->
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-block">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/500x200" alt="Card image cap">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card four</h5>
            <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
        <!-- card four -->
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-block">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/500x200" alt="Card image cap">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card five</h5>
            <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

```
.row {
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, cards, cardContainer, h5, title, i;
    input = document.getElementById("myFilter");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    cardContainer = document.getElementById("myItems");
    cards = cardContainer.getElementsByClassName("card");
    for (i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
        title = cards[i].querySelector(".card-block h5.card-title");
        if (title.innerText.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            cards[i].parentElement.style.display = "flex"
              } else {
                cards[i].parentElement.style.display = "none"
        }
    }
}
```

I expect to have multiple pages of cards that have been 'paginated' and while still maintaining the search filter capabilities

Answer (score 0):

The best way to resolve this issue is to use the overflow css propety. It is different to pagination but can perform a similar role of limiting large sets of data. Here is the updated codepen: https://codepen.io/dnorton94/pen/NWKGagz

```
<!-- results -->
<div class="container" id="resultsContainer">
  <div class="row" id="myItems">
    <!-- card one -->
    <div class="col-sm-3 mt-3">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-block">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/500x200" alt="Card image cap">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card one</h5>
            <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- card two -->
    <div class="col-sm-3 mt-3">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-block">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/500x200" alt="Card image cap">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card two</h5>
            <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- card three -->
    <div class="col-sm-3 mt-3">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-block">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/500x200" alt="Card image cap">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card three</h5>
            <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- card four -->
    <div class="col-sm-3 mt-3">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-block">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/500x200" alt="Card image cap">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card four</h5>
            <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- card five -->
    <div class="col-sm-3 mt-3">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-block">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/500x200" alt="Card image cap">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card five</h5>
            <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- card six -->
    <div class="col-sm-3 mt-3">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-block">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/500x200" alt="Card image cap">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card six</h5>
            <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- card seven -->
    <div class="col-sm-3 mt-3">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-block">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/500x200" alt="Card image cap">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card seven</h5>
            <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- card eight -->
    <div class="col-sm-3 mt-3">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-block">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/500x200" alt="Card image cap">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card eight</h5>
            <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- card nine -->
    <div class="col-sm-3 mt-3">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-block">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/500x200" alt="Card image cap">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card nine</h5>
            <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- card ten -->
    <div class="col-sm-3 mt-3">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-block">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/500x200" alt="Card image cap">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card ten</h5>
            <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- card eleven -->
    <div class="col-sm-3 mt-3">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-block">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/500x200" alt="Card image cap">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card eleven</h5>
            <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- card twelve -->
    <div class="col-sm-3 mt-3">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-block">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/500x200" alt="Card image cap">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card twelve</h5>
            <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- card thirteen -->
    <div class="col-sm-3 mt-3">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-block">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/500x200" alt="Card image cap">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card thirteen</h5>
            <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I created an ID to recognise the div. Then stylized the div using basic css.

```
#resultsContainer{
  width: mw-100;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Here is the overflow documentation with bootstrap: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/overflow/